# Disable action in global toolbar from view

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

In my Eclipse RCP app I have action in application global toolbar. 
I need this: when I select some text in Properties View this action should be disabled.
I can subscribe this action to workspace selection changes, but I can't do anything with selection inside Property Views controls.

Is it possible to disable global action from view?

Comment: It would be unusual to respond to a selection in the Properties View.

Answer (score 0):

you can use à dpendency injection, I guess you use Eclipse4, if this is the case you can use the @CanExecute annotation .

an example similar to what you want to do  is defined in this article

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/eclipse-4-e4-tutorial-part-6-behavior-annotations/

Comment: That does not answer the question of how to control action enablement from a selection in the Properties View.

Comment: there is a example in the article section **@Execute and @CanExecute** it must now adapt it to its case to get selection state in its view, i can't comment for the moment, this is why I posted a answer, otherwise I would have put a comment